# How do I connect my custom registration page to the model?

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studios MVC so please help me out. Every tutorial I have seen is using bootstrap to create registration pages. I created my own using HTML, Javascript, and CSS. Here is the template controller:

```
    public ActionResult CreateAcct()
    {
        return View();
    }

    void ConnectionString()
    {
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-3063L3HI\\SQLEXPRESS; database=betterpathdb; 
    Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    }
    public ActionResult Create(Staff reg)
    {


        
  string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO 
  staff(username,password,first,last,position) " +
  "VALUES('" + reg.username + "', '" + reg.password + "', '" + 
   reg.first + "', '" + reg.last + "', '" + @position + "')";


            con.Open();
            com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", position);

        if (com.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
            con.Close();
            return View("");
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
            return View("Error");
        }
```

Here is the HTML template:

```
<div class="form">

    <form action="Create" method="post">
    <h1>BetterPath Wellness</h1>
    <h4>Create Account or</h4>
    <div>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "IndexLogin")</div>
    <div class="txt-block">
        <label for="us-fname">First:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
        <label for="us-lname">Last:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname">
    </div>
    <div class="txt-block">
        <label for="us-pos">Position:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="position" value="therapy">Therapist
        <input type="radio" name="position" value="observer">Observer
        <input type="radio" name="position" value="admin">Admin
    </div>
    <div class="txt-block">
        <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </div>
    <div class="txt-block">
        <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
        <button id="btn" type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

I think my connection string for "create" is not right?

Answer (score 0):

Add `[HttpPost]` tag to your action. Default verb is `Get`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Staff reg){
   ...
}
```